How to check for success status of Cloud Run Job within Cloud Workflows?
I'm running several Cloud Run Jobs in sequence using Cloud Workflow. After completing Job #1, I want to check for successful completion before moving to Job #2. In testing, I see that Job #1 returns the following results JSON for status:
"status": {
"completionTime": "2024-11-08T17:09:23.947071Z",
"conditions": [
  {
    "lastTransitionTime": "2024-11-08T17:09:23.947071Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Completed"
  },
  {
    "lastTransitionTime": "2024-11-08T17:08:32.322671Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "ResourcesAvailable"
  },
  {
    "lastTransitionTime": "2024-11-08T17:08:35.183828Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Started"
  },
  {
    "lastTransitionTime": "2024-11-08T17:08:32.219908Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "ContainerReady"
  }
],

So, to test for success, I think I want something like:
- check_step1:
    switch:
      - condition: ${step1_result.status.conditions.type == "Completed"}
        next: step2

But, this doesn't work in Workflows. How, then, do I write a proper test condition?

conditions is an array (of objects) and so you can't conditions.type. What you want, but you can't represent as an expression, is step1_result.status.conditions[?type=="Completed"].status=="True". Could you use suceededCount (see ExecutionStatus)?

There may be a way to iterate over the array and return a boolean if there's a object with type=="Completed'. I'm not a user of Google Workflows.

I don't think Workflow supports any JSON query languages, so this condition syntax won't work.

NOT a Workflows user but you piqued my curiosity ;-)
Updated
I tested this using a Cloud Run job (that I had lying around ;-))
main:
  steps:
  - init:
      assign:
      - project: ${sys.get_env("PROJECT")}
      - location: ${sys.get_env("LOCATION")}
      - job: ${sys.get_env("JOB")}
      - result: false
  - run_job:
      call: googleapis.run.v1.namespaces.jobs.run
      args:
        name: ${"namespaces/" + project + "/jobs/" + job}
        location: ${location}
      result: execution
  - step-for-loop:
      for:
        value: condition
        in: ${execution.status.conditions} 
        steps:
        - step-loop-assign:
            assign:
              # True if type=="Completed" and status=="True"
              # Once any `result` is true, then `result` is always true
              # Was unsure how to break from the loop once a result is true
            - result: ${result or (condition["type"] == "Completed" and condition["status"] == "True")}
  - done:
      return: ${result}

This works for me:
gcloud workflows deploy ${NAME} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--source=${PWD}/workflow.yml \
--service-account=${EMAIL} \
--set-env-vars=\
PROJECT=${PROJECT},\
LOCATION=${LOCATION},\
JOB=${NAME}

gcloud workflows execute ${NAME} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud workflows executions describe ${EXECUTION} \
--workflow=${NAME} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format=value(result)

result: 'true'

Original
main:
  steps:
  - step-global-assign:
      assign:
        # Replace with `ExecutionStatus`
        # i.e. `step1_result.status.conditions`
      - conditions: [
            {"status":"True","type":"ResourcesAvailable"},
            {"status":"True","type":"Started"},
            {"status":"False","type":"Completed"},
            {"status":"True","type":"ContainerReady"},
        ]
        # Assume false
      - result: false
  - step-for-loop:
      for:
        value: condition
        in: ${conditions} 
        steps:
        - step-loop-assign:
            assign:
              # True if type=="Completed" and status=="True"
              # Once any `result` is true, then `result` is always true
              # Was unsure how to break from the loop once a result is true
            - result: ${result or (condition["type"] == "Completed" and condition["status"] == "True")}
  - done:
      return: ${result}


Thanks. I've tried about 10 permutations of this loop, and can't get it to work.  Both of these assignments, conditions: $[step1_result.status] and conditions: $[step1_result.status.conditions] yield a TypeError: cannot subscript values of type str (expecting an array, bytes, or a dictionary)

Added example that invokes a Cloud Run job and processes the Execution that results.
